# Javascript basics: variable scope

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and can someone please explain the following code snippet for me?

```
var state=true;
function bob(){ var state=false; }
bob()
```

What should be the state value and why?

Many thanks,
L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of execution, `state` will be `true`, because the function `bob()` defines a local variable named `state` instead of assigning to the global variable of the same name.  However, in the following example, `state` would be false:

```
var state=true;
function bob(){ state=false; }
bob();
```

By omitting the `var` keyword, the JavaScript engine will travel up the scope chain looking for a variable named `state`, until it finds one or reaches the global scope.   This can be further demonstrated with nested functions:

```
var state = true; // global
function bob() {
    var state = true; // local to `bob()` 
    function jim() {
        state = false;
    }
    jim();
    alert(state); //-> false, `jim()` modifies `bob()`'s variable
}
bob();
alert(state); //-> true, `jim()` and `bob()` don't touch the global variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty important fact about ECMA-/Javascript is, there is only **function scope**.

This is one of the very first thing I teach anybody whos learning it. Another concept of Javascript is the **scope chain**. That is in very short words, an internal property which is saved in a context. Each function creates an (execution)-Context and stores all parent context in it's internal [[Scope]] property. Now, when you access a variable name within a function, the Javascript interpreter trys to resolved that variable. The search starts in it's own **Activation object** ( another thing, I'll skip the explanation here) and if it's found the search stops. If the variable could not get found there, Javascript accesses its **[[Scope]]** property and searches the Activation objects from all parent scopes **lexically** (lexical scope...).

The first match for that variable is then taken. If the variablename could not get found anywhere in the *scopechain*, `undefined` is returned.

Now in your snippet, we are creating the variable `state` two times. The first time, the **Global Context** stores the variable in it's **Variable object** (the same thing as an Activation object, but for non-Function context).

The second time, we create `state` in the execution context of `bob()` and Javascript stores it in it's Activation object. So, when we access `state` within the context of `Bob`, its always `false`, because our resolution lookup process begins in our own Activation object.

If we access `state` outside of `Bob` we just will find the variable `state` in the Variable object 
from the Global context (which actually is the Global object itself) and it's `true` there.

---

Further and more precise information about the whole topic:
http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/

Answer (score 0):

```
var state=true; //global scope variable called 'state' => true
function bob(){ 

  var state=false; //local scope variable called 'state' => false, no global 'state' overwritten
  //state = false; would overwrite global 'state'

}
bob(); //call function

//global 'state' remains true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the gloabl "state" value to false, do the following (without (re)declaring a local variable for the bob() function):

```
var state=true;
function bob(){ state=false; }
bob()
```

state Will be:

```
false
```

Comment: Ha, almost the same answer at the same time! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you changed it to the following:

```
var state=true;
function bob(){ state=false; }
bob();
```

Then at the end of execution, `state` will be `false`. This is because the execution context inside `bob()` will look for a local variable named `state`, which it won't find (no `var` before `state` to declare new local variable) and if it doesn't find one it will move up to the next lexical context, where it will see your global variable `scope`, which it modifies to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

When we declare state = true. It is the global scope.
inside function it we are changing value of state. so we are changing value of global scope. So after the change, global value will always be false.